# Count elements in a Dynamic database in Prolog

Tags: dynamic, prolog

Well, I have something like this:

```
 :- dynamic boxes/2.
 boxes([],0).
 boxes([2,3,5],5).
 boxes([1,4,6],2).
```

And within my process I use `assert` and `retract` based on my needs, however at the end of the whole process I need to know how many **boxes** I have, how can I achieve my goal?

I will really appreciate any help, I am so close to finish it up.

Comment: `findall(B, boxes(B, _), L), length(L, NumberOfBoxes)` perhaps?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Too bad I can rate your answer since it is a comment, thank you so much Lurker...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be other ways to do this, but one simple way would be as follows:

```
count_boxes(NumberOfBoxes) :-
    findall(B, boxes(B, _), L), length(L, NumberOfBoxes).
```

To include mat's excellent comment, if all you want in the `findall` is the length of the resulting list, you can reduce memory consumption in the `findall` call as follows:

```
findall(t, boxes(_, _), L)
```

Rather than enumerating a list of the boxes, `B`, it creates a list, of the same length, of atoms, `t`.

Comment: You can save memory with: `findall(` **t** `, boxes(_,_), Ls)`.

Comment: @mat thanks! I had totally forgotten about that method.